# How can I iterate inside a iteration with formfields?

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models eg:

```
class Opening(models.Model):
...
class OpeningDays(models.Model):
      opening = models.OneToOneField(Opening, related_name="days")
...
class OpeningHours(models.Model):
      opening = models.OneToOneField(Opening, related_name="hours")
...
```

and then I create multiple models based on this previous models eg:

```
class StoreOpening(Opening):
...
```

And my issue is when I'm templating the forms for edition. I already created the formsets for the whole data but I want to iterate the data like this:

```
{% for opening in store_opening %}
        {% opening %}
        {{ store_opening_days[forloop.counter]}}
        {{ store_opening_hours[forloop.counter]}}
{% endfor %}
```

but this doesn't seem to work... have any ideas on the best way to do this ?

Comment: you can't do that without making a custom template filter... but really I think the approach is wrong, you should have some foreign key relation between the models and be able to retrieve the appropriate OpeningHours object directly from the current `opening` object in the loop.

Comment: @Anentropic I edited the questions with the relations between the models. Is that information sent to the view ?

would it be something like `opening.days` ?

Comment: if `opening` in the template loop is an `Opening` object then yes

Comment: @Anentropic it's not an Object it's a form

Comment: show the code for the form(s) and formset, also do you have a relation field on/to the `StoreOpening` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I googled deep into the internet and found this guy who was struggling with the same thing as me and he created a something to help us all.

[Nested Formset](https://github.com/nyergler/nested-formset)

White this I'm able to do this:

```
StoreOpening = nestedformset_factory(StoreData,StoreOpening,nested_formset=nestedformset_factory(StoreOpening,OpeningDays,nested_formset=inlineformset_factory(StoreOpening, OpeningHours,extra = 0, can_delete=False), extra = 0, can_delete=False),extra = 0, can_delete=False)
```